# Find parametric equations for the line through the point $(0,1,2)$ that is perpendicular to the line $x=1+t, y=1-t,z=2t$ and intersects this line.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My work so far: Since the lines are perpendicular, the dot product of their direction vectors should be $0$, so $\langle1,-1,2\rangle\cdot \langle x,y,z\rangle=0$.

But I'm not sure where to go from here. I don't know how to express the fact that the line goes through $(0,1,2)$, or that it intersects the other line. How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Suppose that the required line intersects the given line at the point with parameter $a$, that is,
$$(1+a,\,1-a,\,2a)\ .$$
Then the direction of the required line is
$$(1+a,\,1-a,\,2a)-(0,1,2)=(1+a,\,-a,\,2a-2)\ .$$
This must be perpendicular to the direction of the given line, which is $(1,-1,2)$.  Therefore
$$(1+a,\,-a,\,2a-2)\cdot(1,-1,2)=0\ .$$
Can you use this equation to find $a$ and then finish the problem?

Good luck!

---

*Alternative method*.  Let ${\bf u}=(1,-1,2)$ be the direction of the given line.  A vector in the plane of both lines is
$${\bf v}=(1,1,0)-(0,1,2)=(1,0,-2)\ .$$
A vector perpendicular to the plane containing both lines is
$${\bf n}={\bf u}\times{\bf v}$$
and the required line is perpendicular to both $\bf u$ and $\bf n$, so its direction is
$${\bf u}\times{\bf n}={\bf u}\times({\bf u}\times{\bf v})\ .$$