# Find equation for the line that is perpendicular to L1, passes trough p (3,1,-2) and cuts L1

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

I want to find the equation for the line that is perpendicular to $L_{1}$: 
[L1 equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6zbw.png)

Passes through $p=(3,1,-2)$, and cuts $L_{1}$.

I've been finding the dot product between direction vector of $L_{1}$ and direction vector of the requested line:

$$d1\cdot d2 = -a+2b-3c = 0,$$ then both lines must be perpendicular, with $(-1,1,1)$ that's true but I don't know how to make that the line cuts $L_{1}$. Thak you very much.

Comment: Hi Nelson, welcome to MSE! Thanks for making clear what you have tried. The question would be much clearer if you had used MathJax, though. Please see
https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: A duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1238389/265466 once you convert the equation of the line to parametric form.